# How to pass input value to ajax using FormData?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to upload images using ajax and php and I have managed to make it work to a certain level successfully, but I can't make my input's value (ID) pass to my php file.

Here's my scenario.

FORM

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="myform">
        <input type="file" name="images[]" multiple id="image"/>
</form>
```

Button

```
<button type="button" id="uploadimages" name="thing_id" 
value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes
</button>
```

AJAX

```
    $("#uploadimages").click(function () {
        var form = new FormData($('#myform')[0]);

        // Make the ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url: 'uploadimages.php',
            type: 'POST',
            xhr: function () {
                var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                if (myXhr.upload) {
                    myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
                }
                return myXhr;
            },
            //add beforesend handler to validate or something
            //beforeSend: functionname,
            success: function (res) {
                $('#content_here_please').html(res);
                /**/
            },
            //add error handler for when a error occurs if you want!
            //error: errorfunction,
            data: form,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false
        });
    });
```

PHP

```
$get_id = $_POST['']; // This is where I stuck.
```

How can I pass `$row['thing_id']` to `$get_id` variable? I can pass it using another GET ajax call on success, but then I lose the image_id value (I use foreach since I may upload multiple files), so I want to handle it in the same php file.

I didn't include my upload script because it works unless I try to make something using thing_id.

Comment: why not just add a hidden input field with that value & receive it in php? `<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>" name="thing_id" id="thing_id" />`

Answer (score 1):

> in your ajax code pass the data attribute

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'uploadimages.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:{upId:$("#uploadimages").val(),images:$('#uploadFieldId').val()},
        xhr: function () {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if (myXhr.upload) {
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress, false);
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //add beforesend handler to validate or something
        //beforeSend: functionname,
        success: function (res) {
            $('#content_here_please').html(res);
            /**/
        },
        //add error handler for when a error occurs if you want!
        //error: errorfunction,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
```

then you can access the upId in your php file as,i have made an updation so that you can send the upload file field value also to the php file. Change the id so that it matches the field and you can retrieve this field using

> $get_id = $_POST['upId'];
>
> $image = $_POST['images'];

Comment: You now have two data attributes (look lower down) :)

Comment: @Harigovind R  when I remove the data:form from the bottom,  I get Undefined index: thing_id and Undefined index: images error.

Comment: @salep thats because as soon as you remov the form from your data you are not passing the images field to the php.

Comment: @salep This error will go if you pass the value of the images field also instead of passing the whole form

Comment: But I don't use a form, just a button. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @salep i have made some edits to the code please check it out.

Comment: @salep I will not encourage you to use the formdata() function. If you have only one image and one upload button then you can individually pass the field values as shown. Hope it helped you

Comment: Thanks, but still I get undefined index error. I couldn't figure out how it happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76526/discussion-between-harigovind-r-and-salep).

Comment: I solved the issue by using @Rohit Batra's solution, but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have **two** approaches:

**One:**
That `value="<?php echo $row['thing_id']; ?>"` should be the value/id of your form #myform.

**Two:**
You can pass the 'thing_id' the way *Harigovind R* said.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have many options like add a hidden input tag

with `name="uploadimages"` and some desired value

or

Added `name="uploadimages"` to button may work, i am not sure about that